# Where do built-in kernel modules reside?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am confused by how built-in kernel modules work. As per my understanding, one can embed a kernel module when compiling the Linux kernel by setting kconfig option to `MODULE_NAME=y`. Then, it doesn't have to be loaded with e.g. `modprobe`. Built-in kernel modules can be shown with `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin`.

When I execute this command, the list shows `.ko` files. But if they are embedded inside the kernel, why is it showing this? For example:

```
~$ cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin | grep -i bsg    #just picking something random
kernel/block/bsg.ko

~$ cat /boot/config-6.5.0-14-generic | grep -i bsg
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG_COMMON=y    #implying this is a builtin module
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSGLIB=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_BSG=y
CONFIG_SCSI_UFS_BSG=y


~$ modinfo bsg
name:           bsg
filename:       (builtin)
license:        GPL
file:           block/bsg    #why "file"? Isn't it compiled inside the kernel?
...

~$ cat /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/block/bsg.ko
cat: /lib/modules/6.5.0-14-generic/kernel/block/bsg.ko: No such file or directory
```

So my questions are:

- What really  happens to builtin kernel modules and where do they reside inside the system?
- Are they inside vmlinuz and extracted somehow?
- Why do they appear as `.ko` file but are not present in the directory where I would expect them?

Considering they are indeed embedded in vmlinu(x/z), how do they end up being "registered" such that we can find them using `modinfo`? And why does it still have a file (block/bsg) as shown by modinfo if it's in the kernel binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Builtin kernel “modules” (they aren’t really modules) are part of the main kernel binary, `vmlinux` before it’s compressed. They are never extracted as separate entities, they are loaded along with the rest of the kernel.

They appear as `.ko` files in `modules.builtin` to make things easier for other tools, *e.g.* for module dependency analysis. By listing them as `.ko` files, they can be handled in the same way as modules.

When components of the kernel are built-in, but their source files contain module declarations, the information provided there is stored in `modules.builtin` and `modules.builtin.modinfo` (see [the Kbuild documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/kbuild.html#modules-builtin)). `modules.builtin` allows `modprobe` to handle load requests for built-in modules, and `modules.builtin.modinfo` allows `modinfo` to provide information about them. Built-in components don’t have a *filename* (which points to the real `.ko` on disk, for loadable modules), but they do have a file — this is an entry specific to builtin modules, storing the name of the *source* file containing the module declarations ([`block/bsg.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/block/bsg.c) in your example).